# google snappy incrementalcopy function

Tags: c, snappy

The below code is from snappy.cpp from google snappy, Could someone explain how the below function will have the result with **len** **bytes** from **src**.

```
// Copy "len" bytes from "src" to "op", one byte at a time.  Used for
// handling COPY operations where the input and output regions may
// overlap.  For example, suppose:
//    src    == "ab"
//    op     == src + 2
//    len    == 20
// After IncrementalCopy(src, op, len), the result will have
// eleven copies of "ab"
//    ababababababababababab
// Note that this does not match the semantics of either memcpy()
// or memmove().
static inline void IncrementalCopy(const char* src, char* op, ssize_t len) {
  assert(len > 0);
  do {
    *op++ = *src++;
  } while (--len > 0);
}
```

Comment: it does not copy **len copies** of src. It copies *len* bytes. It is an unoptimized version of `memcpy`. I guess the reason a separate function is required is that `memcpy` has lots of optimizations which do not work in edge cases like this.

Comment: yes i meant the samething (len bytes - edited the question for same), also wouldn't src reach '\0' after 3 iterations and how does the copy work. i tried in a simple prog but it only resulted src value not the specified len bytes.

Comment: This function is in case the input and output regions overlap. In the example given, `op==src + 2` So for the third loop, `dest[2]` is set equal to previously set value of `dest[0]` (i.e. `a`)